# How to execute a SQL script with variable from linux

Tags: linux, oracle, shell

I am using oracle database to execute SQL script from bash shell. I assigned the SQL file 'DBMS_STATS.sql' to a variable and try to use the script from linux with sqlplus. But the file is not substituted in the variable. Please help me on how to execute the script with variable.

**Script that i execute:**

```
DBSTATS=/home/oracle/DBMS_STATS.sql
$ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -S '/ as sysdba' @$DBSTATS
```

**Output:**

```
SP2-0310: unable to open file "EXEC.sql"
```

Comment: Your variable is called `DBMS_STATS`, but you refer to `$DBSTATS`. Did you previously declare `DBSTATS=EXEC` somewhere, earlier in that script or exported in your environment?

Comment: @AlexPoole - I didnot declare any other variable before DBSTATS. I updated the variable in question.

Comment: Does the command ``echo @$DBSTATS`` write out ``@/home/oracle/DBMS_STATS.sql`` in your environment?

Comment: Show what is in the file /home/oracle/DBMS_STATS.sql